# How to specify a page to render using `ReportExecution2005.asmx`?

Tags: java, web-services, reporting-services

I'm working on integrating a Java based web application with **SQL Server Reporting Services** by leveraging the Report Execution (ReportExecution2005.asmx) service.

The application leverages the **Report Execution** service by using a library generated by the `wsimport` utility.

All reports are being rendered using the `HTML4.0` output format.

Some of the reports that will be run, render as multi-page reports.

My question is, is it possible to specify to the Report Execution service, which page of the report to render?

So far the only thing that I've been able to find on this subject was from [this](http://printssrsreport.blogspot.com/2011/09/print-ssrs-report-using.html) post which describes how to programmatically print an SSRS report. The post suggests adding a `StartPage` element to the `DeviceInfo` XML fragment.

That didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StartPage` device info does not apply to [HTML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155395%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) format.
The post you reference was using [Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155373%28v=sql.130%29.aspx) format.

You have to use `Section` instead:

> **Section**
>   The page number of the report to render. A value of 0 indicates that all sections of the report are rendered. The default
>   value is 1.

[HTML Device Information Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155395%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)